# 360 Video for oculus/ streetview panorama sequence to video / Spherical Stereoscopic Panoramas

Tags: video-sequence-editor, panoramic

I am new to Blender and am trying to use Blender to make a sequence of Google Streetview shots into a movie to view in an Oculus headset. I used the VSE and put the sequential panoramic photo and produced an AVI file that did run in the Oculus.

Problem was that it was very distorted (like smeared road kill). I obviously need to use the correct settings to get the right Panoramic / Equirectangular view of the photos. I saw that Dalai was working on a patch (https://code.blender.org/2015/03/1451/) that he thought would be incorporated into Blender, but I cannot find the present method for Blender. (The links on that blog page are now disconnected.) Is there a new patch or other download or is it in the Blender present set up.

Comment: You'd have to wrap it on a sphere then render from Cycles as an Equirectangular camera. If the unwrap is wrong the the VSE can't fix it or distort it correctly for you.

Comment: Thanks for the help. My million-dollar question is do I have to wrap every photo around the sphere or will the video sequence editor (or some other great Blender function) somehow only necessitate me to wrap just the first photo and it then auto-magically do all other (different) photos in the sequence the same? (Or do I have to do the full wrap process for every frame?)  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Thanks, David for your guidance. Will the VSE handle separate photos onto a shape in a sequential manner? Or is it simpler to make an AVI video out of the panoramas (as I did) and then wrap that video around the sphere using the VSE? (So its done in one action?) - and render that with an Equirectangular camera ?